# How can I pass the correct variables in a URL in PHP for my paging?

Tags: php

I am working on paging in PHP

- I need it to work on any folder so
  root/  root/folder1/ 
  root/folder1/folder2/ would all work
- It should pass the page number
  variable for the script to work in
  the URL but also retain any other
  variables in the URL that may be
  present with any amount of variables
  passed in tthe URL

Here is what I have so far for the link based on being @

**http://domain.com/test/paging/index.php?var=cool&var2=coo2l&page=1**

---

```
$selfurl = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."";
```

This would create this:   **http://domain.com/test/paging/**

---

```
$qry_str = $_SERVER['argv'][0];
```

This would create this:   **var=cool&var2=coo2l&page=1**

---

So far so good, it works no matter how deep the directory system is and passes ANY and ALL variables that may exist in the pages URL
(NOTE; I know it assumes it is always the index file I will fix that later)

So all of these links below would get passed through my paging links;

http://domain.com/test/paging/?page=1
http://domain.com/test/paging/?var=coo2l&page=1
http://domain.com/test/paging/?var=cool&var2=coo2l&page=1

> Here is the problem, below is an
>   example of my **NEXT** and **PREVIOUS** link,  it works
>   but the problem is after I go to the
>   first page, it will keep adding
>
> **&page=THE-NUMBER-HERE** so when you get to page 3 it
>
> would be like
>
> **&page=THE-NUMBER-HERE&page=THE-NUMBER-HERE&page=THE-NUMBER-HERE**
>
> instead of
>
> **&page=THE-NUMBER-HERE**

**The links;**

```
<a href="<?PHP echo $selfurl;?>/?<?PHP echo $qry_str;?>&page=<?PHP echo $start-$pagesize;?>" class="bluelinkbold">Next</a>

<a href="<?PHP echo $selfurl;?>/?<?PHP echo $qry_str;?>&page=<?PHP echo $start-$pagesize;?>" class="bluelinkbold" >Previous</a>
```

### How can I resolve this path correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's simple:

1. don't use $_SERVER['argv'][0], construct URL by yourself on every request.
2. use preg_replace to remove existing page variable from $_SERVER['argv'][0] then add new one:

   $url_without_page_var=preg_replace('/page=(\d+)/i','',$_SERVER['argv'][0]);

Comment: Thank you so much I have had to live with this bug in my code for over a year now, it works perfect

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when passing a page number after an id variable.
mysite.php?id=16&page=1&page=2&page=1 and so on...
Inspired by Sergei, I remove the existing variables using PHP_SELF, then reload my id and get the new page at the same time.

```
href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] .'?id='. $row['id'] . '&page=' . $pages->next . '">Next
```